# Storing hierarchy of tree levels in recursion using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, tree

```
function formSelectedTree(totaldata, selectedIds) {
    if (!Array.isArray(totaldata)) return;
    for (var item of totaldata) {
        if ((!item.children || item.children.length === 0)) {
            selectedIds.map(function(id, index) {
                if (parseInt(item.id) === parseInt(id)) {
                    item.isSelected = true
                    item.open = true
                }
            })
        } else {
            this.formSelectedTree(item.children, selectedIds);
        }
    }
    return totaldata
}
```

parameters:

- **totaldata-array of objects(find below json)**
- **selectedIds:array of string(Id's of leaf nodes)["1749","1747"]**

The above recursive function is to iterate tree like json object.
We are getting ID's of leafnodes from backend, where based on these ID's , we should select the leaf node and expand the tree structure from parent level.

The selection is handled using 'isSelected' boolean property
The expanding of tree nodes is handled using 'open' boolean property.

I am able to set these properties for leaf node. But facing difficulty to set open=true for its parent/sub-parent levels.

Please find the below sample json object

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "id": 1745,
        "parentId": null,
        "isSelected": false,
        "open": false,
        "children": [{
            "id": 1746,
            "parentId": 1745,
            "isSelected": false,
            "open": false,
            "children": [{
                    "id": 1747,
                    "parentId": 1746,
                    "isSelected": false,
                    "open": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 1748,
                    "parentId": 1746,
                    "isSelected": false,
                    "open": false,
                    "children": [{
                        "id": 1749,
                        "parentId": 1748,
                        "isSelected": false,
                        "open": false
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

can someone help me in achieving this difficulty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This example adds a parentNode property to each node encountered, and uses that to set the "open" property of all ancestors for a given selected leaf node, once it has been located.

```js
function formSelectedTree(totaldata, selectedIds, parentNode) {
  if (!parentNode) parentNode = false;
  if (!Array.isArray(totaldata)) return;
  for (var item of totaldata) {
    // set the parentNode property for each item we traverse
    item.parentNode = parentNode;
    if ((!item.children || item.children.length === 0)) {
        selectedIds.map(function(id, index) {
            if (parseInt(item.id) === parseInt(id)) {
                item.isSelected = true
                item.open = true
                
                // since this is a leaf item that is selected/open, all its ancestors should be open too
                var p = item.parentNode;
                while (p) {
                  p.open = true;
                  // travel up through the hierarchy until parentNode doesn't exist (top level)
                  p = p.parentNode;
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        this.formSelectedTree(item.children, selectedIds, item);
    }
  }
  return totaldata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different approach by using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the `id` and use a short circuit with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), if all id have been processed.

For the update of all children, you could use another recursive function which works for the actual node as well as callback for the children nodes.

If you get strings as `id`, I suggest to convert them to the type of the data before creating a set.

```js
function formSelectedTree(totaldata, selectedIds) {

    function update(o) {
        o.isSelected = true;
        o.open = true;
        o.children && o.children.forEach(update);
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(totaldata)) {
        return;
    }
    return totaldata.some(function (item) {
        if (selectedIds.has(item.id)) {
            update(item);
            selectedIds.delete(item.id);
            return !selectedIds.size;
        }
        return item.children && formSelectedTree(item.children, selectedIds);
    });
}

var data = { "Data": [{ "id": 1745, "parentId": null, "isSelected": false, "open": false, "children": [{ "id": 1746, "parentId": 1745, "isSelected": false, "open": false, "children": [{ "id": 1747, "parentId": 1746, "isSelected": false, "open": false }, { "id": 1748, "parentId": 1746, "isSelected": false, "open": false, "children": [{ "id": 1749, "parentId": 1748, "isSelected": false, "open": false }] }] }] }] };

formSelectedTree(data.Data, new Set([1749, 1747]));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```